# Why this query donst show any info?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have got a problem in this query never shows info.

Here is the code:

```
$db = new DB();
$db->connect();
$query2 = $db->query('SELECT pagado FROM pedidos WHERE email='.$_POST["email"].'');
$row2 = $db->fetch_array($query2);
$query3 = 'SELECT instalado FROM pedidos WHERE email='.$_POST["email"].'';
$row3 = $db->fetch_array($query);
if ($row2["email"] == "S"){
    echo "Su pedido se está instalando";
    echo $resultado3;
}elseif ($row3["email"] == "S"){
```

Comment: did u execute the query?

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: $query is undefined?

Comment: Consider refactoring your query because you are exposed to SQL injection doing the query in the way you are doing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fetch `pagado` from you query and you try to match with email that's wrong

`if ($row2["email"] == "S"){`

it would be

`if ($row2["pagado"] == "S"){`

Also change your query to

```
 <?php
 $db = new DB();
  $db->connect();
  $query2 = $db->query("SELECT pagado FROM pedidos WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."'");
  $row2 = $db->fetch_array($query2);
  $query3 = "SELECT instalado FROM pedidos WHERE email='".$_POST["pagado"]."'";
  $row3 = $db->fetch_array($query3);
if ($row2["pagado"] == "S"){
    echo "Su pedido se está instalando";
echo $resultado3;
}elseif ($row3["instalado"] == "S"){
```

Comment: It would be good to check if the query returned any data before trying to process that data.

Comment: We just provide the way to solve problem of OP.not provide the whole code!!

Answer (score 0):

there is no variable such as `$query` so

change your

```
$row3 = $db->fetch_array($query);
```

to

$row3 = $db->fetch_array($query3);

also you can change your both query and make it into one

```
$query2 = $db->query('SELECT pagado,instalado FROM pedidos WHERE email='.$_POST["email"].'');

$row2 = $db->fetch_array($query2);
```